# Angular Custom Directive Call Inline Function

Tags: angularjs

I am building a custom directive somehow like this

```
app.directive('confirmation', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
     onConfirm:"&"
    },
    link: function (scope, element) {
      $(element).confirmation(function(){
        onConfirm: function(){
          scope.onConfirm();
        }
       });
    }
  };
});
```

and use it like this

```
    <script>
        function DoSomethingOnConfirm(){
                     //Do Something;
                    }
    </script>
<a confirmation on-confirm="DoSomethingOnConfirm()">Delete</a>
```

I don't have access to the controller so the function "DoSomethingOnConfirm()"
is a normal javascript function, how could I call this function inside the directive, I tried calling it directly but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question i understand that you wanted to call a javascript from your directive. I believe in this case you wanted to call some function when user click anchor tag directive.

Here is the code

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('confirmation', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {         
        element.on('click',function(){
            eval(attr.fname);
        });
    }
  };
});
function DoSomethingOnConfirm(){
    alert("Are you sure want to delete?");
}
function AddMe(){
    alert("Added!!!");
}


</script>

<a confirmation href="javascript:;" fname="DoSomethingOnConfirm()">Delete</a>
<a confirmation href="javascript:;" fname="AddMe()">Add</a>
```

Instead of getting external function name from scope, i am getting it from attribute and triggering that function.

I hope this helps